# How to fix SharePoint Online sidebar navigation?

Tags: sharepoint-online, menu, menu-item

I am looking an issue in SharePoint Online site. Here menus are not getting collapses while I am clicking on other 1-Level menus.
[image]

In the above image first I click on the Pages menu to see the submenus inside this. After that I clicked on the Inspections menu to see its sub-menus, on the same time Pages sub-menus hierarchy is not get collapsed. Can anyone please advise what is the way here how menus will get open/ close hierarchy? Currently this is menus are getting collapse if I am clinking on the upward caret icon.

Answer (score 1):

You mean, when you expand "Inspection", the navigation bar will automatically collapse other expanded menus (for example:Pages), right?

If this is the case, we cannot achieve it. In SharePoint, when you expand an expanded menu, you can only manually collapse other expanded menus, otherwise these expanded menus will all be expanded and displayed.

[image]

Comment: Yes  If I expend the Inspection sub-links, Other menus expended should automatically collapsed.

Comment: Hi, Mobile Test. According to your description, there is no out-of-the-box way to realize your design. If there is any solution in the future, I will share with you as soon as possible. Have a nice day!